# Custom circle progress view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I search a lot, but cant find control like this in internet.
Can you help me to do this my own?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO9ec.png]

Comment: check this demo http://code4app.net/ios/CircularProgressControl/54b4dd2ee247413e143a9685

Comment: You searched a lot : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=circular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take white circle image like you displayed in above image and try following code.

```
- (void)startSpin
{
    if (!animating)
    {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
    }
}

- (void)spinWithOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions) options
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0f
                      delay: 0.0f
                    options: options
                 animations: ^{
                     imgViewCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgViewCircle.transform, M_PI / 2);
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         if (animating) {
                             // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                         } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                             // one last spin, with deceleration
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                         }
                     }
                 }];
}
```