# circle UIBezierPath with stork animation

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a circle with UIBezierPath and add a stork animation to circle like this:

[image: circle animation]

I don't know how to build this with UIBezierPath because I'm new to Swift. I tried some code on some question on stack overflow but no luck.

Comment: can you show me your code what you tried to draw above Indicator?

Comment: thanks but i just try for build and i don't have code and this is not indicator . a circle with UIBezierPath with animation

Comment: ok so what you want here a readymade code in answer ? here we are for help to solve problem where developer are stuck not for whole code to get from answer and use it in your project. Please try once with `UIBezierPath` and show your efforts for above animation.

Comment: i just need some example of UIBezierPath animation . but ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this link as a reference.

[Custom circle progress view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495396/custom-circle-progress-view/28495807#28495807)

Take one image with same gradient

[image]

and rotate that image. You will get what you want.

Comment: thanks but if i want to use of uibezierpath or cashapelayer , how i can build this